# SQL phpmyadmin remove posts from cat id exclude condition

Tags: posts, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a sql code for wordpress database that use for deleting posts from specific cat id for specific time duration and I always use this code and it is working fine.

```
DELETE
    a, -- DELETE from posts
    b, -- DELETE from term relationships
    c  -- DELETE from postmeta
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE e.term_id = 2 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), post_date) > 180;
```

but the issue is I want to keep those posts from the specific cat id that have another cat id checked.
I know my description is confusing you so I make an example :
Imagine I want to delete posts from cat id [2] for time more than 180 days but some of these cat id [2] posts are in another cat id for example [1] and I don't want delete these posts. Just delete posts that belong only to cat id [2].
the posts that are in cat id 2 and 1 should not delete.
So in the above code I need to add additional code to can keep those posts that are in cat id [1] anyway.
Right now the above code delete all posts in cat id [2] and also the posts in cat id [2] and [1]
**Let me explain this in another way:**

> I need a correct code that any posts from cat id [1] never and should not be
> deleted. There are many posts that are in cat id [1] and another cat
> id that should remain and never delete with this code.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're doing this using a raw or direct SQL query than using the relevant WordPress functions?

Comment: @SallyCJ yes I need to delete these posts after months because the database need to clean and also these posts are nofollow and noindex and just need to keep them for a while and some of these posts are important that will add in cat id 1 and should keep for ever

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use direct SQL to do the database cleaning. You should instead use the WordPress function to properly delete a post and all of its associated data, e.g. meta, revisions and comments. Using that approach will also ensure the post/term/comment/etc. caches are correctly updated.

Comment: the posts are too many and just can delete from phpmyadmin. So I just need to change the above code to fix this issue

Comment: If you have WP-CLI, you could [create a custom command and run something like `wp your-command --category_id=2`](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/commands-cookbook/). Even without WP-CLI, you could still create a PHP function/script and run it when necessary. But if you insist on using direct SQL, then be prepared to face issues like on the `wp-admin` page for managing categories, the post count are incorrect (until for example after you created a new post).

Comment: it's much easier, safer, and more compatible to do this using PHP code, particularly via WP CLI. Note that you're volunteering for bitrot by doing this though, and that a MySQL/MariaDB database is designed to handle _millions_ of rows in a table or more. Direct SQL statements don't flush caches, trigger actions/filters, and can cause problems. E.g. your category post counts will be incorrect after running this query

Comment: @TomJNowell can you privide a PHP code about that?

Comment: I actually described how to do that in a comment on your answer, but you deleted your answer then reposted with modifications it rather than editing

Answer (score 0):

finally I find right code with helping by ChatGPT

```
DELETE p
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr1 ON (p.ID = tr1.object_id AND tr1.term_taxonomy_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr2 ON (p.ID = tr2.object_id AND tr2.term_taxonomy_id = 20)
WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), p.post_date) > 180
AND tr2.term_taxonomy_id IS NULL;
```

> Lets try another way to write new code. consider I want to delete all
> posts from category ID 2 in time duration more than 180 days except
> those post that are in category ID 20 too . I mean there are for
> example 2000 posts in category ID 2 in time duration +180 days and 500
> posts of them are in category ID 20 too. so I expect just 1500 posts
> will delete and keep those 500 posts.

I try this code and it is working fine